# How to config debugger for scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I was able to run debugger on Scala code but not anymore with Intellj IDE Community Edition 2020.1.1 (April 2020 ) ...

For a Scala-Play application it used to be direct (just launching the sbt console then push the "little green bug button", I suppose it was something like "attach process" under the wood [attach remote process](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/attaching-to-local-process.html)

Now I get :

**Error running 'Debug sbt shell': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:37609): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"**

1. File > Setting... > SBT Executor
   VM parameters are set to : -Xmx512M -Dsbt.log.noformat=true
2. File > Setting... > Build,Execution,Deployment > Debugger
   Scala building server Port = ??? Is this related
3. Run > Edit Configuration > Run/Debug configuration > Remote
   Argument for JVM are :
   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=37609
   [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-scala.html)

Any ideas are welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what was broken/mising in my configuration :

File > Setting... > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools
sbt
**tick Enable debugging for sbt shell**

- the 2. is not related to the debug stuff but to a plugin named "sbt executor" that were installed, I disabled it (I don't know what it was for)

So to recap my working scala debugging remote sbt conf with Intellij CE 2020.1.1 is :

Now in sbt shell I see something like :

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:42329,suspend=n,server=y -Xdebug etc...
```

1. Run > Edit configuration >
   Run/debug configuration, issued from the template "remote"
   [image: configuration intellij sbt debug shell]
2. File > Settings > Build,execution,deployment > Build tools > sbt
   [image]